# Error with \usepackage{mhchem}. It was working and now it cannot compile

Tags: errors, mhchem

The whole report cannot even compile now! And the pdf cannot open any more! I narrowed down the problem to  `\usepackage{mhchem}`. I was using version 3 (if it matters) but i also tried  writing `version=4`. I read here that there is an issue when updating latex. So i tried uninstalling and installing the previous version that was working and still nothing. An example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:HDO}
        \ce{C$H_{1.4}O_{0.4}$ -> 1''C$H_{2}$ '' + 0.4H2O}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It does nothing. trying to finish compile or just say:

> Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) why are you using those $ in math mode? And what does `_{1.4}` of hydrogen actually mean.

Comment: On a recent TeX installation, I don't get the error "undefined control sequence" but complaints from the `mhchem` package about characters that cannot be interpreted. The complaints go away when I remove the `$` signs (math mode is not required for subscripts to work) as well as the quotes `''`.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error `Unexpected input character` for the `'`. They are not supported (yet). But in your example, I don't even know what they should represent. What is `1''`?

By the way, this input definitely did never work with any version of mhchem.

You don't need the `$`, just remove them.

`\ce{CH_{1.4}O_{0.4} -> 1CH2 + 0.4H2O}` works just fine. (Although 2+0.4*2=2.8, not 1.4.)

Unfortunately, up to v4.04 (which seems to be included in TeX Live 2016, from reports I get) there was a bug, causing an infinite loop of `Unexpected input character` when running in nonstop mode, as is the case when compiling within TeX editors.