# using R' notation in mhchem

Tags: mhchem

When trying to use the typical `R and R'` notation for writing chemical formulas with the `mhchem` package, I get the `unexpected input character` error. Adding spaces around the apostrophe does not work (as is the usual case with reaction arrows in `mhchem`. This suggests that apostrophes are not supported yet. Is there a correct modification to this issue?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{R3C=CR'3} % results in error
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As evidenced by [this response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341362/98145), apostrophes are not supported by mhchem. Enclosing the apostrophe in `{}` will work.

Example from question:

`\ce{R3C=CR'3} % error`

`\ce{R3C=CR{'}3} % working`